# Rest API not honoring Http header:location

Tags: http, header, location

I have a php method which is setting header(location: "SomeUrl"). On executing the method from browser I am getting the correct output i.e. "SomeUrl" is invoked. But when I make a rest call to the same method I am getting the output as returned by the function instead of "SomeUrl" but in my response header 'location' I do see "SomeUrl". 
Now if I exit my method I am getting the output as "SomeUrl".

Please could someone help me understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Meaby you "rest call" don`t have set up SomeUrl as location parametr?

set up this as location in every rest call it look like they try make new call.

Comment: On using  getResponse().redirectSeeOther("SomeUrl") the response received by rest call is "SomeUrl", but  header(location: "SomeUrl") does not work. If I exit my method then header(location: "SomeUrl") is honored. I want to understand why is the first case header(location: "SomeUrl") did not work.